# Multiple apps in git remotes when trying to access rails console

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have two git branches, `staging` and `production`, and I deployed them on Heroku in the same Heroku acccount. Suppose my app names are `app1.heroku-app.com` and `app2.heroku-app.com` and the remote names are `heroku-staging` and `heroku-production`,respectively. I deployed both apps on Heroku. After I login to Heroku from the console using `heroku login` and then try to access a Rails console using `heroku run rails c`, I get this message :

```
 ▸    multiple apps in git remotes
 ▸    remotes: heroku-staging heroku-production
```

How can I access a console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's only one Heroku remote, `heroku` can infer which you want. When there are multiple (or if you want to access an application that doesn't have a remote in this Git repo, or when you're not in a Git repo at all), you need to use the `--app` option to specify which application you want a console on.

```
$ heroku --help
Usage: heroku COMMAND [--app APP] [command-specific-options]

$ heroku run rails c --app app1
$ heroku run rails c --app app2
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being able to specify the app as a per-command flag, if you'd like for there to be a default environment, setting the environment variable `HEROKU_APP` to the app you want will make it so that `heroku` commands don't rely on git config.

```
$ heroku logs
 ›   Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
...
$ export HEROKU_APP=app1
$ heroku logs
2018-12-31T03:56:34.888350+00:00 app[web.1]: 1.2.3.4 ...
```